# Tomcat6 deployment

Tags: tomcat, deployment, servlets

I am very new to Servlets and Tomcat deployment. 
I am following 'HeadFirst Servlets and JSP' book to learn Servlet. I did the following steps to create and deploy the servlet on tomcat.
1. Created a servlet 
2. Created web.xml

Chapter1 Servlet
Ch1Servlet


Chapter1 Servlet
/Serv1

1. Under tomcat > Webapps, created a directory called 'ch1'
2. Inside ch1, created WEB-INF and copied web.xml into it.
3. Inside WEB-INF created classes, and copied .class file into it.
4. Ran the startup.bat
5. Launched http://localhost:8080/ch1/Serv1, and I am getting HTTP status 404.

But, http://localhost:8080/ loads correct page.

I am stuck with this problem. I know it is really simple issue, but I couldnt find answer anywhere.
Please help me to fix this .
Many Thanks,
Ann

Answer (score 0):

That's a really tedious way to write a servlet! Get an IDE such as [Eclipse IDE for Java EE developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/jee.php) and write your servlets.

Follow this directory structure for your webapps. Ignore the struts-config.xml.

[image: J2EE webapp structure]

Also, here are some nice links to get you started with working with Eclipse EE.

http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-tomcat/index.html

http://www.java-tips.org/java-tutorials/tutorials/introduction-to-java-servlets-with-eclipse.html

http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/tutorials/BuildJ2EEWebApp/BuildJ2EEWebApp.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Lemme try this.

Comment: it is tedious, but i think there is value in manually setting up the file system without the IDE (in a learning sense).  maybe your servlet mapping is not set up correctly in web.xml?

Comment: @rquinn - I agree. But I wouldn't recommend directly creating directories inside the webapp. What I would instead suggest is creating a similar directory structure elsewhere, bring your work to a logical conclusion, and copying it at once inside tomcat's webapp folder so that the context won't be reloaded innumerable number of times whenever a change is made.

Comment: that sounds like the best solution